# Line indents inside table matching the fontawsome symbols indents

Tags: macros, indentation, fontawesome

I am using some `fontawsome` symbols inside one column in a table. When the text is too long the second line of text is not aligned with the first, which looks bad. I want to somehow fix this, preferably without changing the layout of the table too much and keeping the macros I have created.

What I get from MWE:

[image]

What I want:

[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontawesome}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\definecolor{icons}{HTML}{46A247}
\newcommand{\locationsymbol}{\faMapMarker}
\newcommand{\calendarsymbol}{\faCalendar}


\newcommand{\CVdate}[1]{\textcolor{icons}{\calendarsymbol}\hspace{1em}#1}
\newcommand{\CVlocation}[1]{\textcolor{icons}{\locationsymbol}\hspace{1.4em}#1}
\newcommand{\CVevent}[2]{\CVdate{#1} \newline \CVlocation{#2}}

\newenvironment{CV_table}{%
  \par\addvspace{\topsep}\noindent
  \begin{tblr}{
    width=\textwidth,
    colspec={@{} X[l,2] X[l,4] X[l,3] @{}},
    column{1} = {font=\bfseries},
    rowsep=0.5\baselineskip
  }%
}{\end{tblr}\par\addvspace{\topsep}}


\begin{document}

\begin{CV_table}
    a & a & \CVevent{01.01.2019 - 01.02.2020}{Some long location name spanning multiple lines} \\
    b & b & \CVevent{10.12.2013 - ongoing}{Location B}
\end{CV_table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: as you are in a table anyway put the icons on their own in a first column and the text can then wrap in a second column

Comment: why would you need manual adjustment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the definitions of the macros to:

```
\newcommand{\CVdate}[1]{\begin{tblr}{c l}\textcolor{icons}{\calendarsymbol} & #1\end{tblr}}
\newcommand{\CVlocation}[1]{\begin{tblr}{c l}\textcolor{icons}{\locationsymbol} & #1\end{tblr}}
\newcommand{\CVevent}[2]{\begin{tblr}{c l}\textcolor{icons}{\calendarsymbol} & #1 \\
\textcolor{icons}{\locationsymbol} & #2\end{tblr}}
```

This seems to have worked, but putting in a vertical line in the `CV_table` (`|`), it is clear that this goes beyond the bounds of CV_table:

[image]

How can I make it fit inside the column in CV_table even if the textwidth is changed using `minipage`?